# Get objects with certain value(objectId) in array with Parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a Place object, containing an array with objectIds for Tag objects.
An example of an array:

```
[[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"FavoriteTag","objectId":"Toc5sVlzVd"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"FavoriteTag","objectId":"cUxcl0IFFv"}]]
```

My first workflow way too slow:

1. query each Place object, get the array and parse it to find each objectId
2. get the corresponding Place with the objectId

The workflow I'm trying:

1. Find the objectId of each matching Tag object
2. Put these objectIds in a ArrayList
3. Get each Place object that contains a matching objectId from the arraylist

I don't know how to do step 3.
I'm trying:

```
parseQueryFavoritePlaces.whereEqualTo("tags", arrayListTagsObjectIds);
```

and

```
parseQueryFavoritePlaces.whereContainedIn("tags", arrayListTagsObjectIds);
```

but no luck so far.
Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this a shot:
 `query.whereContainedIn(String key, Collection<? extends Object> values)`

According to the Parse documentation this adds a constraint to the query that requires a particular key's value to be contained in the provided list of values.

Here's the [ParseQuery documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html) if you think that might be useful!